# How to change the default alignment of a caption using the ctable package?

Tags: tables, captions, ctable

I searched through the manual of `ctable` handy package and couldn't find any help there, to change the default centered caption to left alignment. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\ctable[
caption = The caption is centered by default,
]{lll}{
}{
\toprule
 No & Mininmal Working Example Column One & Mininmal Working Example Column Two \\ 
  \midrule
  1 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 1 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 1 \\ 
  2 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 2 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 2 \\ 
  3 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 3 & Mininmal Working Example Cell 3\\ 
  \bottomrule
}

\end{document}
```

MWE result:
[image]

Note: `ctable` v1.26

**How can one change the default centered alignment setting of a caption?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
[...]
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false}
[...]
```

`RaggedRight` also allows hyphenation if the the caption is longer than one line